# Accessing object properties with JSTL - Spring and hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jstl

I have Persons(id, name,..), Division(id, name, parentId, level...), and PersonDivisoin (id, personId, divisionId....) tables. Application uses hibernate framework to map relations with onetoone mapping between Person and Person Division, onetomany mappings between Division and PersonDivision.. below is an example data from Division table..

```
 _ _ _ _ _ _ __ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
| id | name | parentId| level|
 -----------------------------
   1   XYZ               dept
   2   ZYW      1        team
```

and PersonDivision table is...

```
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ __ _ _
| id | personid | divisionId| 
------------------------------
  1      1           2
```

So I am having trouble getting the value of parent division name on the front end side if I have a person object..

Person class looks something like this..

```
 class Person{
   String name;
   int id;
   PersonDivision personDivision;
 }
```

PersonDivision class..

```
 class PersonDivision
 {
    int id;
    @OneToOne Person person;
    @ManytoOne Division division;
}
```

on the front page(jsp), if have to access a Person's team, I can do something like, ${person.personDivisoin.divsion.name}

but how would I access Person's "department"? Ideally it should take the parentid from "Division" table and get the name from it.. ${person.personDivisoin.divsion.parentId} gives Parent Division id but I am not sure how to retrieve its name with using JSTL.. the best I could think of is that, sending a list of all the divisions as a 2-D array with id and name and on the view, retreieve name from id..

I would like to know if there are any better/simpler methods to do this.. thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you need a `PersonDivision` class?
Since the association between `PersonDivision` and `Person` is mapped as `@OneToOne` wouldn't it be easier to just map the `Division` as a field in `Person`?

Something like this

```
class Person {
   @Column
   String name;

   @Id
   int id;

   @ManyToOne
   Division division;
}
```

This would allow you to access the division name as `${person.division.name}`.

In addition to that, if you define the `Division` as follows, you should be able to access the parent division with the same ease (`${person.division.parent.name}` to get the parent name).

```
class Division {
   @Column
   String name;

   @Id
   int id;

   @ManyToOne
   Division parent;
}
```

You can find more info and examples on [Hibernate documentation about associations](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/associations.html)

Comment: @abhagat.. thanks for the suggestion on Division class.. it surely looks the right way to go.. regarding Parentdivision.. that legacy table contains few more columns like createddate,deactivateddate etc... I think they created those columns thinking that a person  may have more than one record in the PersonDivision table but only one "active" record.. and I guess they later decided to drop that idea and have only one record per person..

Comment: Then this is what you're looking for: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/associations.html#assoc-unidirectional-join-m21. It represents the association in the same way, but it uses an explicit association table like the one you have.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `parentId`, you can have `@ManyToOne Division parentDivision`. It will be the same in the database, but hibernate will fetch the parent division (and the whole hierarchy, actually, if you don't set the relation to lazy).